# Python search string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance

i have a Problem and hope you can help me. I have a .csv data and with 3 rows. ('string', number, 'string' ). This data has 500 Megabyte and 10 000 000 rows and I also have an List with 1 500 000 strings in it. These strings are part of the first row of the dataframe. I want to get a dataframe with 1 500 000 rows('string', number, 'string' ). I read different articles About vectorization but im not an expert in python. 
What is the best Option to performe this Task.

```py
outfile = pd.read_csv (dataname, sep='\s+', Header = none )
outfile.columns = ['picturename', 'number', 'part']

outerdata = outfile['picturename'].values

for var in all_file_names # this is the list with 1 500 000 rows
  puffer = outfile.loc[outerdata == name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
puffer = outfile.loc[outfile['picturename'].isin(name)]
```

---

Example:

```
print(df2)
    C   D   E
0   b   a   l
1   h  bb   h
2   r   f   b
3  cc   g   a
4   d   r  dd
```

---

```
name=['a','b','d']
df2.loc[df2['C'].isin(name)]
```

Output:

```
   C  D   E
0  b  a   l
4  d  r  dd
```